# How to verify HID input (CRC) in Unity Input System?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hid, crc

I read a custom HID device response using the new Input System. I have a script that reads the HID data (`ReadValue()` from each control) and put it into a struct variable that is then read by other relevant systems in game. Another script has `InputAction` defined to fire on specific HID action (i.e. Button pressed).

The HID data contains CRC sum I must verify before passing the values to the structure and before firing events.

Where should I verify the CRC sum to prevent Actions from being triggered?

Edit:
As requested some parts of the code:

**SensorResponse.cs**  (defines data frame)

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 0x28)]
public struct SensorResponse : IInputStateTypeInfo 
{
    public FourCC format => new FourCC('H', 'I', 'D', ' '  );
    [FieldOffset(0x00)]    
    public byte zeroTmp;        //0x00
    [InputControl(name = "startFrame", layout = "Integer", format = "BYTE")]
    [FieldOffset(0x01)]
    public byte startFrame;        //0x00
    [FieldOffset(0x02)]
    [InputControl(name = "command", layout = "Integer", format = "BYTE", displayName = "command")]
    public byte command;       
    ... 
 [FieldOffset(0x18)]
    [InputControl(name = "Switches", layout = "Integer", format = "SHRT", displayName = "Switches")]
    ...
    [InputControl(name = "cArmM1", layout = "Button", bit = 2,  displayName = "cArmM1")]
    [InputControl(name = "cArmM2", layout = "Button", bit = 3,  displayName = "cArmM2")]
    ...
    public Switches switches;
```

**ControllerDevice.cs** (defines device)

```cs
[InputControlLayout(stateType = typeof(SensorResponse))]
public class ControllerDevice : InputDevice
{
    ...
    public ButtonControl cArmM1 { get; private set; }
    public ButtonControl cArmM2 { get; private set; }
    ...

    protected override void FinishSetup()
    {
        base.FinishSetup(); 

        cArmM1 = GetChildControl<ButtonControl>("cArmM1");
        cArmM2 = GetChildControl<ButtonControl>("cArmM2");
    ...
    }
```

**ControlScript.cs** (defines actions)

```cs
public class ControlScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {

        InputAction M1Btn = new InputAction(binding: "<ControllerDevice>/cArmM1", interactions: "hold(duration=1)");
        InputAction M2Btn = new InputAction(binding: "<ControllerDevice>/cArmM2", interactions: "hold(duration=1)");
       
        M1Btn.canceled += (e) => { RecallMemory(Switches.cArmM1); }; //trick to capture both click and hold action
        M1Btn.performed += (e) => { SetMemory(Switches.cArmM1); };
        M2Btn.canceled += (e) => { RecallMemory(Switches.cArmM2); };
        M2Btn.performed += (e) => { SetMemory(Switches.cArmM2); };

        M1Btn.Enable();
        M2Btn.Enable();
    }


}
```

There is also a script that I use to read data from the response:

```cs
public class Actions : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        FillSensorResponse();
    }
    private void FillSensorResponse()
    {
        if (ControllerDevice.current == null)
            return;

        var sensorResponse = new SensorResponse();

        sensorResponse.command = (byte)ControllerDevice.current.command.ReadValue();
        sensorResponse.commRev = (byte)ControllerDevice.current.commRev.ReadValue();
        ...
        sensorResponse.switches = (Switches)TSPControllerDevice.current.Switches.ReadValue();

        if (Crc8.Verify(sensorResponse))
        {        
            //some preprocessing
            ...
            //setup sensore response for other scripts
            Simulation.SensorResponse = sensorResponse;
        }
        else
            Debug.Log($"CRC invalid!");
     }
}
```

Comment: You you `have a script that reads the HID data (ReadValue() from each control) and put it into a struct variable that is then read by other relevant systems in game` so I'd suppose you do the validation in there ..? Then your other scripts would rather attach their listeners to that first script and you don't directly use `InputAction` anywhere at all ...

Comment: Are you asking _where_ to verify the CRC, or _how_ to verify the CRC?

Comment: @derHugo Yes, if i do as you said I would need to implement all the InputAction mechanisms. Also, it seems to be step backwards, loosing part of nice functionaloties. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @MarkAdler I asked where, becouse I thought there must be some binding or extension or something that I can use to check the CRC between data arrival and events firing. Like in the processor of a a InputAcion. I know how to verify CRC.

Comment: Never tried but it might be even possible to have custom processing of actions via a custom [`Processor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Processors.html) problem with those is: input and output has to be the same type so either the input already contains the checksum as well or you could try [`CompositeBinding`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/ActionBindings.html#composite-bindings) and do your check there .. would have to be done in all the places though

Comment: @derHugo I'm going to check it. HID data contains CRC sum that I must verify.

Comment: @derHugo maybe I can make a mechanism, where if CRC check fails, all InputActions get disabled? This might introduce at least one sample lag though.

Comment: Is the checksum in each individual action or do you receive like packages for the entire HID state?

Comment: @derHugo I receive whole package, 41 bytes in total, the last one is a CRC sum. Few bytes are interpreted as buttons. I have simple actions like press/release but also "hold" - implemented with `interactions` in `InputActions`

Comment: I think it would help to see your InputActions and how you have things set up / your code/settings to convert those bytes to inputActions in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the **rdjadu** [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/crc8-of-the-custom-hid-input.1390918/), I managed to solve that problem:

1. I implemented `IInputStateCallbackReceiver` interface in my `InputDevice`.
2. then, I calculated the crc8 sum inside `OnStateEvent`, and called `Change` when it is valid:

```cs
    public void OnStateEvent(InputEventPtr eventPtr)
    {
        var response = StateEvent.GetState<TrinitySensorResponse>(eventPtr);

        var crc = Crc8.Calculate(response);

        //alternatively:
        //var o = (byte[])this.ReadValueFromEventAsObject(eventPtr);
        //var crc = Crc8.Calculate(o);

        if (crc == 0)
            InputState.Change(this, eventPtr);
        else
            Debug.LogWarning("CRC Failed!");
    }
```